# Socket bulk reading returned an array of zeros

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, file-transfer

I've been writing a simple file transfer program which opens a TCP connection to a server, negotiates the terms of the file transfer (over TCP) and streams the file from the client to the server. The problem is large files almost always corrupt. I logged the socket `InputStream` and `OutputStream` and found that while the data matches at first, after several kilobytes an interesting desync occurs.

At a certain point the receiving socket starts reading `0` while the sending socket continues sending the file data.

Example:

```
Server: ..., -75, 82, 34, -109, 50, -51, 52, 9, -14, -70,...
Client: ..., -75, 82, 34, -109, 50,   0,  0, 0,   0,   0,...
```

However After a bit it recovers

```
..., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -51, 52, 9, -14, -70,...
```

You'll note it resumes where it left off. The only problem is now I have a bunch of zeros in my file and the end of the stream will not be recorded into the file (as the file length is sent ahead of time).

**NOTE:** this only seems to happen some of the time (more often than not)

The streaming code itself:

Sender:

```
<header stuff, I checked it works fine>

long dataLeft = 0;
while(dataLeft < packet.payloadSize){
    packet.remaining = packet.payloadSize-dataLeft;
    byte[] temp = new byte[packet.remaining<8192?(int)packet.remaining:8192];
    packet.inStream.read(temp);
    stream.write(temp);
    dataLeft+=temp.length;
}

stream.flush();

<Rest of the code>
```

Receiver:

```
public boolean streamPayload(OutputStream out) throws IOException{
    long dataLeft = 0;
    while(dataLeft < payloadSize){
        remaining = payloadSize-dataLeft;
        byte[] temp = new byte[remaining<8192?(int)remaining:8192];
        inStream.read(temp);
        out.write(temp);
        dataLeft+=temp.length;
    }
    return true;
}
```

`long dataLeft` acts as the index btw.

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how I can fix it/compensate for the issue? I know I can't tell if a zero is intended so I can't just listen for the issue by watching the output.

Comment: Because all send/receive functions may send/receive less than requested number of bytes. For example, `inStream.read(temp)` may read less than `temp.length` number of bytes. So, the tail elements of this array will be equal to zeroes.

Comment: There's my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this will solve your problem but one thing you are doing wrong is ignoring the amount of data transferred.

```
InputStream in = //from somewhere
OutputStream out = //to somewhere
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int read = -1;
while ((read = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
out.close();
int.close();
```

You could be reading data without receiving any and then writing 8192 byte buffer that is empty because you didn't check if anything came through.

Comment: This is almost certainly the correct answer.  OP: if you ignore the return value from `in.read()`, you *will* corrupt your data.

Comment: THANKYOU! I see, I may ask for it to fill a 8K buffer but it may not fill it all the way. THANKYOU AGAIN.